How do I create seperate env for each node service in a nx integrated monorepo?
I'm trying to build a nodejs (Express) monorepo using nx, and here I'm facing issues with env variables. I want to use the seperate env files for each service in a monorepo but it's coming undefined if I use .env file inside the each service. But it is working when I keep the env files in root level of the monorepo. How do I use env for seperate repo ?
I tried putting env in seperate service and it's not working, I have to keep the env in root level but I don't want to keep the env file at the root level.
This is the error I'm getting when I try to read env inside the service
  error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/monorepo/.env'

How do I make sure the env should be read from each service folder right now it is reading from root level only and its throwing error as the root level .env file is not available.
I want to make sure the env is loaded from this directory /Users/monorepo/apps/app1/.env instead of /Users/monorepo/.env

Hi! Loading .env files is not tied to nx specifically, rather each service in the monorepo. Please provide details of what services you are running, e.g. Next/Nest/Express etc.

Updated the question, I'm using express framework.

And where do you specify the .env you want to load? Can you paste an example of the code?

I've added the .env inside the service folder. The folder structure looks like this
monorepo
-> apps
-> service1 starts (The service1 cannot read .env inside the service1)
-> .env
-> app.ts (here trying to read the env)
-> service1 ends
-> .env (The service1 can able to read this .env)
-> package.json
Since it's integrated monorepo just one package.json

In app.ts, how do you read the env?
